# Swift code can not find the symbol of the data

Tags: json, swift, xcode, generics

I am new to swift . I am trying to convert json into model by using swift . I am using generic functions to complete the functions . Here is the structure of the json .

[image: screenshot of the json structure]

Here is the model I created based on jason .

```
 import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let photos: [Photo]
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let id, sol: Int
    let camera: Camera
    let imgSrc: String
    let earthDate: String
    let rover: Rover

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, sol, camera
        case imgSrc = "img_src"
        case earthDate = "earth_date"
        case rover
    }
}

// MARK: - Camera
struct Camera: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let roverID: Int
    let fullName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case roverID = "rover_id"
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }
}

// MARK: - Rover
struct Rover: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, landingDate, launchDate, status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case landingDate = "landing_date"
        case launchDate = "launch_date"
        case status
    }
}
```

Here is the code in generic function.

```
func getModel<Model: Codable>(_ type: Model.Type, from url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Model, NetworkError>) -> ()) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            completion(.failure(.badURL))
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
        
    }
```

I am trying to call this function form controller  but it is showing the error **Value of type 'Post' has no member 'data'**

Here is the code to call the function.

```
class ViewModel {
    
  private   let networkManager  = NetworkManager()
    
    private var rovers  = [Post]()
    
    func getStories (){
        networkManager
            .getModel(Post.self, from: NetworkURLs.baseURL) {[weak self]result in
                
                switch result{
        
                case .success(let response):
                    self?.rovers = response.data.camera.map{$0.data} **// error on this line** 
                case .failure( let error):
                    print( error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: `response.data.camera.map` has a few things wrong with it, and it's unclear what the result you're looking for is. First off, you're asking to decode a `Post`. As the error says, `Post` doesn't have a data property. Next, *none* of your structures have a `camera` element (although you have a struct *named* camera). Thirdly, you're trying to `map` that property, but you have no arrays in your model. I'd suggest pasting your JSON into [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) and comparing your models to what is generated there.

Comment: After the fist struct the photo it self an array . I am trying to get all items from rover struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response` is of type `Post` which has no property `data`.  You'll need to extract your photos array from the response, and then map across that array and retrieve the `rovers` property from it.

I think what you meant to write was

```
self?.rovers = response.photos.camera.map{$0.rover}
```

However even that won't work as your data structures don't match your JSON.  From what can be seen, `rover` is a property on `photo` not on `camera`.

You will need to validate the JSON -> Model mapping

**EDIT** after JSON linked in comment below:

Using the JSON from the API, it confirms that `camera` and `rover` sit at the same level in the JSON:

```
{
  "photos": [
    {
      "id": 102693,
      "sol": 1000,
      "camera": {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "FHAZ",
        "rover_id": 5,
        "full_name": "Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"
      },
      "img_src": "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01000/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486265257EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG",
      "earth_date": "2015-05-30",
      "rover": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Curiosity",
        "landing_date": "2012-08-06",
        "launch_date": "2011-11-26",
        "status": "active"
      }
    },
    ....
```

So you will need to change your data model:

```
struct Photo : Codable{
    let id : Int
    let sol : Int
    let camera : Camera
    let imgSrc: String
    let earthDate: String
    let rover: Rover
}
```

and then to decode it

```
self?.rovers = response.photos.map{$0.rover}
```

nb. in Swift all struct types should be capitalised by convention.

Comment: I re generated the json with quick type but still not found the value camera

Comment: Here is the api for joson

Comment: https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: expaned the answer with the JSON, and you can see boththe camer and rover properties of photo (also: always post the actual JSON, not a screenshot)

Comment: Now it giving it showing new error

Comment: You can see from the JSON it is an array of entities that you have modelled in the Photo struct.   Each element in the array has keys for id, sol, img_src, earth_data and rover.  You will only need to mention in the struct those properties you want.  if all you want is the rovers, you could just have `struct Photo: Codable  { let rover: Rover} and no CodingKeys.  All depends what data you wish to extract.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Rover' to closure result type 'Post'

Comment: You'll need to define your rovers property as an array of `Rover`, not an array of `Post` n your viewModel!

Comment: Thank you now the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Your struct of type Post does not have a member called "data", indeed.
You seem to be assuming, that your response object is of type Photo - but the error message is telling you, that it is of type Post, which only holds an array of Photo objects.

Try something like:

*response.photos[0]* to get the first Photo object out of the array - if there is one.
Then, assuming you got one *response.photos[0].data* gives you a Camera object already - you seem to be calling via the type, instead of the member name.
So in case you want to go one step further and access a Rover object, you need to do: *response.photos[0].data.data*

I see, that you want to extract several Rovers, supposedly one from each Post, but this will clash with your initial rovers variable being assigned a type of an array of Posts - this means you have to change it to [Rover]. I'm not sure if the map-function is actually suitable for what you want to do here.
Using a loop, iterating through the Posts and appending Rover objects to the Rover array would be the "manual" way to do it.

Hope this helps.

Edit: because you have edited your model mid-question, I can't see where "Post" has gone now. My reply might only fit the way the original question was posted.

Comment: I change the value